# HARN NAD 83 to NAD 83

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, nad83

Is there a way to convert HARN NAD 83 to NAD 83?

I'm using a software that requires shape files to be NAD 83.

This is what I want to convert it to:

Projected Coordinate System:

```
NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  1968500.00000000
False_Northing: 13123333.33333333
Central_Meridian:   -99.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    28.38333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    30.28333333
Latitude_Of_Origin: 27.83333333
Linear Unit:    Foot_US
```

Geographic Coordinate System:

```
GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

This is what the layer has current, tried to use project tool but keep receiving errors

Projected Coordinate System:

```
NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  1968500.00000000
False_Northing: 13123333.33333333
Central_Meridian:   -99.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    28.38333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    30.28333333
Latitude_Of_Origin: 27.83333333
Linear Unit:    Foot_US
```

Geographic Coordinate System:

```
GCS_North_American_1983_HARN
Datum:  D_North_American_1983_HARN
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Comment: Yes, the Project tool in the ArcGIS toolbox has transformations to convert between HARN NAD83 to NAD83.  What is your full coordinate reference system?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your errors. Just saying you keep getting errors is not helpful, they could be errors not related to the transformation, but something else.

Answer (score 2):

This should generally work, but you'd have to combine transformations. In this case, convert from NAD83 to WGS84, then from WGS84 to NAD83 HARN. ArcMap selects these transformations automatically when you input your original and desired coordinate system.
This is what it looks like for me:

[image: Screenshot of Project tool settings.]

It runs without errors. As far as the accuracy, you will lose some. The table posted in [this article](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005929) should give you an idea.

Comment: Look for a transformation like NAD_1983_To_HARN_East_Texas or _West_Texas. That's the most accurate transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It is always best to keep comments such as "It would be helpful if you could post your errors. Just saying you keep getting errors is not helpful, they could be errors not related to the transformation, but something else." in the comments section rather than adding it in the body of your answer.